# Multiple post types in archives (filter?)

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, archives

I'm trying to get all custom post types to appear in my archive sections on a site, including monthly, tagged, author archives. At the moment, I've thought of something like:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'sw_custom_post_type_includes');

function sw_custom_post_type_includes($query) {

        $post_type = array('post','custom1','custom2','custom3');

        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);

        return $query;

}
```

But I don't want to use pre_get_posts, as this messes with all queries. Is there a filter for, in effect, pre_get_archives? Can't seem to find a solution on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sw_custom_post_type_includes($query) {
        $post_types = array('post','custom1','custom2','custom3');
        if ( ! is_archive() && ! in_array( get_post_type(), $post_types ) )
                return $query;

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );

        return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'sw_custom_post_type_includes');
```

Comment: Hey, I tried something like this and it interferes with all queries on the archive page. Including things in the sidebar, the wordpress native menu system, it all seems to get overridden. Any way around that? (I take it there isn't an archive specific filter)

Comment: Still note sure if I got your Q (and what's your fn is supposed to do), but see update.

Comment: @kaiser Using a [slightly modified](http://pastebin.com/xU3P4YSh) version of your code you posted above, but `post_type=page` is not working (it returns all of the results again) yet every other post type works as intended. I don't believe this is due to anything I added (basically I just pulled in all of the public post types in an array) -- have any thoughts on why it's not picking up on that?

Comment: @Zach [Take a look at the comments of this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/e2wCasR4). Copypasta will never work out. Always go through stuff character by character, line by line. And always comment what stuff should do, before writing it. This way you won't loose your mind and it's easier to check.

Comment: @kaiser really appreciate you making that - I'll make those modifications and see where I am with that. Thanks again!

Comment: @kaiser I struggled with this one for a while and ultimately came up with a [solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56852/query-query-varpost-type-not-set-for-pages) but I think something might be missing here... any input on that question would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: @Zach From a brief look: Moving this to a new question seems to be ok. You should still link both questions with an edit.